# Hiding Multiple Elements in JTable via ButtonClick

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am currently working on a tool which edits data dynamically in a JTable. I want to hide the targeted row whenever a button is clicked. Right now I am using RowFilter. Whenever the button isClicked, a new filter is created:

```
            RowFilter<MyTableModel, Object> rowFilter = null;
        try {
            rowFilter = RowFilter.notFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(((String)dataTable.getValueAt(dataTable.getSelectedRow(), 0)),0));

        } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
            return;
        }
        sorter.setRowFilter(rowFilter);
```

This only works for one element each time the button is clicked. I want to stay them hidden, so you can continously hide elemtens in the table. It is important to mention that I do not want to delete the rows, just hide them.

I hope someone has an easy answer for this, looking for quite a while now.

Comment: The best way to get us to fully and quickly understand your problem would be if you were to to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method `sorter.setRowFilter(rowFilter);` is replacing the filter every time you "add" a new filter. So, it's "forgetting" the old rules. What you have to do is edit the existing filter to include the new rules for filtering.

Check out the **[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html)** for more details.

In any case, I extracted a part of the documentation which you should try to implement.

#### From RowFilter Javadoc:

> Subclasses must override the include method to indicate whether the
>   entry should be shown in the view. The `Entry` argument can be used to
>   obtain the values in each of the columns in that entry. The following
>   example shows an `include` method that allows only entries containing
>   one or more values starting with the string "a":
>
> ```
> RowFilter<Object,Object> startsWithAFilter = new RowFilter<Object,Object>() {
>    public boolean include(Entry<? extends Object, ? extends Object> entry) {
>      for (int i = entry.getValueCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
>        if (entry.getStringValue(i).startsWith("a")) {
>          // The value starts with "a", include it
>          return true;
>        }
>      }
>      // None of the columns start with "a"; return false so that this
>      // entry is not shown
>      return false;
>    }
>  };
> ```

This means that the `include()` method is going to return `true` or `false` depending if an item should be shown.

Therefore, you should only set the `RowFilter` once, and reimplment the `include()` method to match all the rules you currently have set upon your view.

Comment: This helped me quite a lot. For everyone who wants to know how i solved it: I created a boolean variable for each of my data element in the table and marked it as true when the element was selected with the button. Then I sorted for elements which values where false.